# Android: execute runnable in interval with Lambda

Tags: java, android, lambda

The way to execute code every X millis in Android is the following pattern:

```java
    void test(Handler handler) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something

                // Do it every 200ms
                handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, I've started changing the code to use lambdas whenever possible. Changing this pattern to lambda has one problem: `this` inside the lambda references the outer class, so it can't be used in `postDelayed(...)`.

To make it work, I have to keep a reference to the lambda. However, that reference can't be in a local variable. This means finding a meaningful name for this lambda-runnable and storing it as a class member:

```java
    private Runnable intervalRunnable;

    ...

    void testWithLambda() {
        this.intervalRunnable = () -> {
            // Do something

            // Do it every 200ms
            handler.postDelayed(intervalRunnable, 200);
        };
        handler.post(intervalRunnable);
    }
```

So the code is more "modern", but arguably uglier and less maintainable.

Is there another way to solve this problem? I love lambdas, but I'd rather not keep those references at the class level. Between these options, I prefer to stick to the anonymous class pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) says that:

> **15.27.2. Lambda Body** ... 
>   Practically speaking, it is unusual for a lambda expression to need to talk about itself (either to call itself
>   recursively or to invoke its other methods)...If it is necessary for a
>   lambda expression to refer to itself (as if via this), a method
>   reference or an anonymous inner class should be used instead.

Which I read as basically saying "if you need a recursive lambda, don't use a lambda."

Based on this, it seems that we are stuck with having something along the lines of your second example, in which you save off the lambda reference to the class (though arguably that's more or less equivalent to using a method reference).

You could try to hide the fact that you are using a method reference:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable everyXMillis(Runnable inner, int ms) {
    return () -> {
        inner.run();
        handler.postDelayed(everyXMillis(inner, ms), ms);
    };
}

void testWithMethodReference() {
    handler.post(everyXMillis(() -> {
        // do something
    }, 200));
}
```

...but...yuck! If you're concerned about having ugly and unmaintainable code, it seems you're better off with the more verbose anonymous Runnable.

Comment: So unless I'm reading this wrong, in your "yuck" suggestion you're now wrapping the actual Runnable with another one... I thought about something like that, but it adds even more ugliness IMHO. I guess I'll stick to good old anonymous classes for now. I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything.